# Execute reader requiring an open connection

Tags: c#, connection-string

Hi I have been creating an order form for a project and having difficulty getting the day number on to a data row. I have the below code but am getting the error 'ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.'. any help on this would be appreciated.

```
 private void cmbSelectDay_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //variable for case statement
        int day = 0;

        string Sql = "Select deliveryDayNo from standardOrderDetails order by deliveryDayNo";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);  // ...
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn); //there is an error happening here that im not too sure about that would need to be fixed first. but once its fixed this should all work.
        SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (DR.Read())
            {
                cmbSelectDay.Items.Add(DR[0]);

            }


                //case statement to take the selected value of the combo box and assign a new value to the variable "day" acordingly.
                switch(cmbSelectDay.SelectedText.ToString())
                {
                    case "Monday":
                        {
                            day = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Tuesday":
                        {
                            day = 2;
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Wednesday":
                        {
                            day = 3;
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Thursday":
                        {
                            day = 4;
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Friday":
                        {
                            day = 5;
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Saturday":
                        {
                            day = 6;
                            break;
                        }

                }


                // DataRow dr = dsLeprechaun.Tables["standardOrderDetails"].Rows.Find(day);
                DataRow dr = dsLeprechaun.Tables["standardOrderDetails"].Rows.Find(day.ToString());
                dgvOrder.Rows.Add(dr["deliveryDayNo"].ToString());


            lblSelectCategory.Visible = true;
            lstBoxSelectCategory.Visible = true;


    }
```

Comment: Um, you haven't called `conn.Open()` to open the connection... (You should also use `using` statements, and ideally a somewhat higher level API, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... open the connection:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // consume data
    }
}
```

You might also want to look into tools that help with ADO.NET, such as "dapper" - for example, if I assume that this data is a string, we could shorten all of this to just:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    var days = conn.Query<string>(
        "Select deliveryDayNo from standardOrderDetails order by deliveryDayNo"
    ).ToList();
    // now add the items from "days"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Open the Connection Object `conn` before calling the `ExecuteReader()` method.

Try This:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn); 
conn.Open();                                 //Add this statement
SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to open the connection

```
conn.Open();
using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while(reader.Read())
    {
      //code here
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I added the connection and the code seems to run on down but I am getting another error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".